# Using variables in a postgres sql block

Tags: postgresql, variables, plpgsql

Can you have an SQL block  that accepts a variable  for input, uses that variable in a join and returns a result set.

The kicker is that I have been asked to do this outside a function - i.e. within an SQL block.

So, for example, I want to pass the value `1234567890` to the variable `v_hold`:

```
DO $$
declare
   v_hold integer;
BEGIN

 select * from t_table_A where ID = v_hold ; 
--return alert_mesg;
END$$;
--$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

The testing I've done says that in order to return a result set, you have to define that in a `RETURN TABLE` declaration. I've tried to define this outside a function, but I haven't figured it out.

Can this be done outside a function - i.e pass a variable and return a result set based on a select statement which references a variable in the where clause?

Comment: You can't return a result from an anonymous DO block

Comment: The core of the problem seems to be different definitions of "SQL block". A `DO` command is not an "SQL block", even though its default language PL/pgSQL has "blocks" - which wouldn't be called "SQL blocks". And `RETURNS TABLE` (with `S`) is only available in a `FUNCTION`. The prepared statement suggested by @aengus may be the compromise. Be aware that it lives and dies with the session (unless deallocated earlier) - unlike a function, which is a persisted object.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a prepared statement.  For example:

```
    PREPARE myStatement (int) AS SELECT * FROM t_table_A where ID = $1;
```

To then run the statement use the execute command:

```
    EXECUTE myStatement(1234567890);
```

Comment: I used aengus' response - that was the best fit for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-do.html):

> DO executes an anonymous code block, or in other words a transient anonymous function in a procedural language.
>
> The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, returning void. It is parsed and executed a single time.

You could generate your code block with a shell script and get the sort of effect you are looking for.